# Seem to be making valid JSONarray object but how to get php to process it?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I'm sending a string to a php script and trying to make a jsonarray out of it for processing and putting it into an sql table. I send a string from an android application to the server:

```
[{"name":"bob","datetime":"2012-04-14 10:40"},{"name":"Anonymous","datetime":"2012-04-14 10:40"}]
```

I used http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the jsonarray and it is valid. When I have the following php script:

```
<?php

$json_as = stripslashes($_POST["json_a"]);
//$out.=json_decode(jsoninfo);
$realjson = json_decode($json_as, true);

//print $json_as;
//echo $realjson[name];
//print $realjson[name];
print $json_as;

?>
```

I see get the following info in my LogCat:

```
The Response text is [{"name":"bob","datetime":"2012-04-14 10:40"},{"name":"Anonymous","datetime":"2012-04-14 10:40"}]
```

I've been trying to use this for reference without luck: http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/

But when I try to change the php script to pring something out from the variable $realjson, nothing comes back. How do I get the information out of the json string I am sending?

Comment: You've printed $json_as, which **is** the original json string

Comment: try 'trim($json_as, "[");trim($json_as, "]");' to remove the square brackets at start and end

Comment: how do I take the information out of the string?

Comment: for example, how do I get the first name and second name in the json string and then echo it back?

Comment: remove square brackets and try decoding the json then, should work

Comment: What happens if you var_dump( $realjson ); rather than print $json_as;

Comment: @liquorvicar I get : response text is NULL :-(

Comment: @siidheesh I think that's only valid json if it isn't an array.

Comment: @siidheesh I think you were right. I think I got it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent a string in JSON format, then used the following code:

```
$json_as = stripslashes($_POST["json_a"]);
trim($json_as, "[");
trim($json_as, "]"); 
$realjson = json_decode($json_as, true);
//$uses = "name";

mysql_select_db("thoughtsdata",$con);

foreach($realjson as $item) {
    $name = $item[name];
    $datetime = $item[datetime];
    //processed code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete tutorial to send and recieve [JSON data between PHP and Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php).

I hope this can help you.

Query:

> http://localhost/testJson.php?data=[{%22name%22:%22bob%22,%22datetime%22:%222012--04-14%2010:40%22},{%22name%22:%22Anonymous%22,%22datetime%22:%222012-04-14%2010:40%22}]

PHP CODE :

COde :

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];

print_r(json_decode($data));

?>
```

Result :

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => bob [datetime] =>
>   2012--04-14 10:40 ) [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php) => stdClass Object ( [name] => Anonymous
>   [datetime] => 2012-04-14 10:40 ) )

Comment: I'm able to send and receive json already, but I have not been able to send json arrays (I can just receive them). As of now I have to loop through everything to upload multiple entries. So I keep having to make and break a connection with the server which doesnt seem very efficient.

Comment: sorry can't get...the person have no ready code for that..sorry

Comment: got something might help you..posting it